# How to add local Instance server when we Can't find SQL Server Installation Center 2017 exe file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2017  but I can't find the SQL Server 2017 Installation Center exe named in the start menu or anything exe file. Here below I have shared the snapshots of the exe shortcut file location.

I am able to connect to the different servers that I can access and see the data in the SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

**My question**:  I need to create a Local Instance for few Databases in my machine. Where I am unable to do it due to the Installation Center exe being missing. How Can I achieve this?

*I see these are the Services that got installed on my machine.*

[image: Microsoft SQL Server 2017]

*From the below Image here I didn't see the SQL Server Installation Center 2017 exe file. Where I am looking to add an instance to my server.*

[image: Configuration Tools path]

My SSMS Insatlled Target Location Path :

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
> Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"

**For Reference**:  I have checked in my other different machine in the target location of SQL Server Installation Center it was pointing to LandingPage.exe in this path :

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup
> Bootstrap\SQL2017\x64\LandingPage.exe"
> [image]

I have highlighted in the above image In the same way, I have checked for the Setup Bootstrap Folder was missing in my machine. I have shared the missing Setup Bootstrap folder path in the below image.

[image]

In Installed Programs, I see there is no Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Setup.As I shared in below image.
[image]

To explain clear I have added the images that made my question was lengthier. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, After trying many alternate methods. I have done it by installing SQL server 2017 Express in Basic Installation.

After the installation, I have got the Setup Bootstrap folder and also SQL Server Installation center.exe 2017 have been installed.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20211022_130915

C:\SQL2017\Exp_ENU

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\SSEI\Resources
```